# Method call with nullable and not nullable generic array

Tags: generics, kotlin

I would like to write a function in Kotlin which takes a String array and sums up the length of all items in the array. I thought about something like this:

```
fun sumItems(values: Array<String?>): Int {
    var sum: Int = 0
    values.forEach { if(it != null) sum += it.length }
    return sum
}
```

This works great but unfortunately I can not call this method for `Array<String>` because I get a type mismatch error then. I also can not create a function `sumItems(values: Array<String>): Int` because it has the same JVM signature. I could cast my argument to `Array<String?>` but this is unsafe.

So is there any better way to do this in Kotlin?

Comment: do you really need that function as is? isn't `fun sumItems(values: Array<String>) : Int` already enough? If not, then just use `Array<out String?>` as parameter type. Yoni Gibbs answer already shows this and also how that method can even be more simplified...

Comment: I would declare it as `sumItems(values: Array<String>)` and when I need to pass an `Array<String?>` I would filter it with `filterNotNull`.

Comment: I would take the same route as @m0skit0. That makes the code way more clearer and cleaner ;-)

Comment: However filterNotNull returns a list :(

Comment: The problem with calling `filterNotNull` is that you're creating a second collection in memory. And you're having to do the loop twice. In most cases this is probably negligible, but if working with a lot of data it's not the most efficient way.

Comment: well... I think that performance impact is negligible and I even go so far, that I would rather try to omit that `Array<String?>` instead and try to work with non-nullable types here instead... ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
fun sumItems(values: Array<out String?>) = values.sumBy { it?.length ?: 0 }
```

You might want to make it an extension method instead:

```
fun Array<out String?>.sumItems() = sumBy { it?.length ?: 0 }
```

This will work for both `Array<String>` and `Array<String?>` because of the `out` modifier on the generic type.  What this states is that the `values` parameter (or the receiver of the extension method) must be an array that **produces** nullable strings. Obviously `Array<String?>` produces nullable strings so that's valid to pass in.  But `Array<String>` **also** produces nullable strings, because strings can always be cast to nullable strings. This is explained in more detail [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html).

Comment: I think that's not what is being asked: *"I can not call this method for Array<String> because I get a type mismatch error then"*.

Comment: You can call it for both `Array<String>` and `Array<String?>`. I'll update my answer with more details..

Comment: Oh you're correct, I'm not very used to use out/in modifiers, very nice answer!

Comment: while being the correct answer to solve the problem, I can only suggest to eliminate the `null` values as soon as possible so that the code is not filled with tons of null-safe calls ;-)

Comment: Why doesn't this work with `lists` as well? If I have `fun foo(c: MutableCollection<out String>)` I can call `foo(mutableListOf<String>())` but not `foo(mutableListOf<String?>())`. Any notes to that as well?

Comment: It should be `fun foo(c: MutableCollection<out String?>)` (note the `?`). If you do that you can call it both the ways you mention above.

Answer (score 2):

Even though Yoni Gibbs answer is correct, I would rather take another route here, i.e. working with a non-nullable type, e.g.:

```
fun sumItems(values: Array<String>) = values.sumBy { it.length }
```

And as also m0skit0 mentioned in the comment: if you really have `null` values in your list, filter them out before making the sum, e.g.:

```
val arrayWithNulls = arrayOf("hello", null, "world")
arrayWithNulls.filterNotNull()
              .let(::sumItems)
```

Or better yet: just skip that method and do:

```
arrayWithNulls.filterNotNull()
              .sumBy { it.length } // or .sumBy(String::length)
```

Why introducing a new function, if applying existing ones already suffices?

Try to eliminate the null values from your array early. Otherwise your code just gets more complex (adding lots of null-safe things) and that makes the code just less readable. That way you could also skip that `filterNotNull`.

Comment: Just be aware of my comment on the question itself: calling `filterNotNull` creates a new list in memory.  Most probably the overhead here is negligible, but if you're working with large data sets you might want to avoid this. You could call `asSequence` on the original array to get round this though.

Comment: I see no real reason to keep `null` values within an array... that performance impact is negligible and probably completely avoidable ;-) Even if we would work with large data sets (then I assume even more that there are no `null` values), I would rather filter it once and use non-nullable types everywhere else...